# why event not fire in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

could you please tell me why  click event is not firing when I am taking `selector` in `object`;
here is my code
https://jsbin.com/seregezahe/1/edit?html,js,output

```
(function(){
  $(function(){
    var config ={
      btn:$('#btn'),
      hello:$('.hello'),
       bodyClickEvent: $("body"),
       overlayClick: $('.overlay'),
      closeBtnSelector: '#closeBtn',
    };
  config.btn.click(function(){
    $('#container').append($('#overlay').html())
    $('.popupdata').html('<div class="hello">xxxx</div><a href="javascript:void(0)"  id="closeBtn" >X Close</a></div>');


  })
  config.bodyClickEvent.on("click", config.closeBtnSelector, function () {

    //why it is not working
    config.overlayClick.fadeOut(500);
               config.overlayClick.remove();
    // below code is working fine
               //$('.overlay').fadeOut(500);
               //$('.overlay').remove();
            });

})
})()
```

**why these two line are not working**

```
 config.overlayClick.fadeOut(500);
               config.overlayClick.remove();
```

when I run my code it show a `button` when I click on button `some html is show` with **close button** text .When I click close button it is not `fadeout` my html and remove.

Comment: Please try to use good grammer

Comment: where is the issue ?

Comment: "Why these two line not working", "When I click close button it not fadeout my html and remove", "why event not fire in jquery".  There are plenty of errors

Comment: ok .,,Sorry for that ..I try to edit my question

Comment: @Xufox Thanks for the spelling mistake

Comment: `$('.overlay')` doesn’t exist from the beginning. It’ll be an empty jQuery object.

Comment: Element does not exist when you reference it.

Comment: @Xufox what is is correct way do this

Comment: Read the linked question.

Comment: @epascarello can I add selector in object when It is `overlay` data coming is DOM

Comment: is it a correct way https://jsbin.com/cefocabiji/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var config ={
  btn:$('#btn'),
  hello:$('.hello'),
  bodyClickEvent: $("body"),
  overlayClick: $('#overlay'),
  closeBtnSelector: '#closeBtn',
};
```

Because the element `#overlay` is not exist when you call `$('#overlay')` above, so the `$('#overlay')` return an empty list.

The following code should work:

```
var config ={
  btn:$('#btn'),
  hello:$('.hello'),
  bodyClickEvent: $("body"),
  overlayClickSelector: '#overlay',
  closeBtnSelector: '#closeBtn',
};

config.bodyClickEvent.on("click", config.closeBtnSelector, function () {         
  $(config.overlayClick).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the config object after updating the dom

```
config.btn.click(function(){
    $('#container').append($('#overlay').html())
    $('.popupdata').html('<div class="hello">xxxx</div>'+
                         '<a href=""  id="closeBtn" >X Close</a></div>');
    config.overlayClick= $('.overlay');
    config.closeBtnSelector = '#closeBtn'
    return false;
  })
```

Comment: There actually is a `<div class='overlay'>`, but it’s not in the DOM when `$('.overlay')` runs, thus it’ll be empty.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your are selecting the elements before they are added to the page. You need to populate the selectors after you add them to the page.

```
....append(...);
....html(...);
config.overlayClick = $('.overlay'); 
...
```

or you need to select the items instead of using the variable.